# Confused about vuejs-templates webpack-simple code snippet

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am a newbie of javascript.

Start to learn Vue.js by reading the examples.

But I am confused about the code snippet of [vuejs-templates/webpack-simple](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple).

From [line 25](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/blob/master/template/src/App.vue#L25)

```
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
```

I am wondering why code can't be written like this

```
  data: () => {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
```

I have tried both code, the same result.

I can't understand from reading Vue.js document.

Please help me to understand this code snippet.

Thank you for taking time reading my problem.

Comment: Both are the same thing, the first one actually is a shorthand of the second.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not about *why it isn't*, but more about *why should it*.

In both cases, you are defining a function, which is member of an object literal. In `es6` there is the feature of [method properties](http://es6-features.org/#MethodProperties), which is used as a shorthand notation. See also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar to `es6` syntax.
Now I understand it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to take care when you want to use arrow functions over the method properties.

Arrow functions provides the lexical `this` so sometimes you could find yourself in situation where `this` doesn't refer to correct context (It should be Vue object itself but it pointent to parent object, in your case probably window).

VueJS Docs gives pretty same warning:

> Don’t use arrow functions on an instance property or callback (e.g.
> vm.$watch('a', newVal => this.myMethod())). As arrow functions are
> bound to the parent context, this will not be the Vue instance as
> you’d expect and this.myMethod will be undefined.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Properties-and-Methods

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I also saw that on document.